# the chechkbox keeps the last selected row

Tags: visual-foxpro, foxpro

I have a form with a grid, the first column is not in the packages table, I added a checkbox. For example, if I select the second row in the checkbox, it stays selected even after closing the form.

[image]

The value of the checkbox is not stored in the table, how do I do it so that when the form is reopened the checkbox does not have any rows selected?

```
  SET PATH TO "C:\Users\ives\Documents\Visual FoxPro Projects\delivered\dbfs"

  USE IN 0 SHARED packages

  Thisform.packages.RecordSource = "packages"
  Thisform.packages.column2.ControlSource = "packages.code"
  Thisform.packages.column3.ControlSource = "packages.name"
  Thisform.packages.column4.ControlSource = "packages.address"
  Thisform.packages.column5.ControlSource = "packages.phone"
  Thisform.packages.refresh
  thisform.packages.setfocus()
  thisform.refresh
```

The value that is configured in the check1.value is 0, after configuring the recordsource and the grid source control, I have this code but the problem continues.

Answer (score 1):

Every column in a grid has to have a ControlSource. If you're not specifying one, then the grid will choose one somewhere.

The typical way to use a checkbox in a grid for selection is to add a column to the table or cursor you're working with to hold that value, or to set up a cursor with a 1-1 relationship to your original table to hold the value.